# POST form dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, submit

I have a form to which inputs are dynamically added upon click of button that calls an append function. Once the form is submitted, I only have access to the inputs that were created on page load. I have double checked this fact using the following debug code. The alert indeed does not display the dynamically generated IDs.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
  });
```

The script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++;
            var printCounter = document.getElementById("product_counter");
            printCounter.value = x; 
            //increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div>' +
        '<div class="input-group">' +
        '<span class="input-group-addon">Nom</span>'+
                    '<input id="vch_invoice_item['+x+']” name="vch_invoice_item['+x+']” value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">'+
                 '</div>'+
                '<div class="input-group">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>'+
                  '<input id="vch_invoice_description['+x+']” name="vch_invoice_description['+x+']" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">'+
                '</div>'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon">Prix à l’unité</span>'+
                  '<input onclick="bindPriceMask(this)" onfocus="bindPriceMask(this)" id="vch_invoice_unitcost['+x+']” name="vch_invoice_unitcost['+x+']” value="" type="text" class="unit form-control" placeholder="">'+
                '</div>'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon">Quantité</span>'+
                  '<input onclick="bindQtyMask(this)" onfocus="bindQtyMask(this)" id="vch_invoice_quantity['+x+']” name="vch_invoice_quantity['+x+']” value="" type="text" class="qty form-control" placeholder="">'+
                '</div>'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon">Taxe Fédérale</span>'+
                  '<input onclick="bindTaxMask(this)" onfocus="bindTaxMask(this)" id="vch_invoice_fedTax['+x+']” name="vch_invoice_fedTax['+x+']” value="" type="text" class="taxf form-control" placeholder="">'+
                '</div>'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
                   '<span class="input-group-addon">Taxe Provinciale</span>'+
                  '<input onclick="bindTaxMask(this)" onfocus="bindTaxMask(this)" id="vch_invoice_provTax['+x+']” name="vch_invoice_provTax['+x+']” value="" type="text" class="taxp form-control" placeholder="">'+
                '</div>'+
        '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Supprimer</a><br><br><br>'+
                '</div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9763
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your developer console open? See any errors? Anything?

Comment: Check your quotes. Use `"`  instead of `”`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9763/  The form is in a modal window, click the little square to open it. The button image is not rendering.

Comment: @sectus I changed them, now the serialize debug code displays the stuff but the php form still doesnt see them through post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Some of my closing quotes were made with my keyboard in french and hence were wrong. 
2.I took out the [ ] in IDs.